# Getting function name from nested decorator

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

I am trying to get correct function name while using 2 decorators.

1> profile - `from memory_profiler import profile`

2> custom timing decorator

```
def timing(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time()
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time()
        print 'Elapsed time: {} - {}'.format(wrapper.__name__, end - start)
        return result

    return wrapper
```

They are used in the following order as defined below

```
@timing
@profile
def my_function():
    something.....
```

Problem is both functions work well individually but when used together I don't get correct name via the timing decorator. I always get `wrapper` instead of the actual function name.

How do I get the actual function name instead of getting "wrapper" as the function name?

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of the decoration? First @profile then @timing?

Comment: Have you tried using `f.__name__` instead of `wrapper.__name__`?

Comment: @sophros if I change the order of the decoration then `profile` decorator always shows memory usage of `wrapper` function.

Comment: @0x5453 Changing `wrapper.__name__` to `f.__name__` didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealt with the same problem today. In my case, I have a few decorators that extend other decorators by composition, and also take input arguments themselves. I needed to log some contextual information about the function being decorated, so I was naturally inclined to use the `func.__name__` attribute, and I was getting the `"wrapper"` string like you.

My solution might not be the most elegant one (by far) but it's *legal* and it worked

```py
def log_context(logger):
  def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      logger.debug({
        func.__name__: {
          "args": args,
          "kwargs": kwargs,
        },
      })

    # Persist the name of the original function
    # throughout the stack
    wrapper.__name__ = func.__name__
    return wrapper

  return decorator
```

Then I can have something like this without a problem:

```py
@log_context(logger)
@a_similar_decorator(logger)
def foo(x, y=None):
  pass

foo(1, y=123)
```

This would output something like this:

```
{'foo': {'args': (1,), 'kwargs': {'y': 123}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's useful and will keep this in mind.